# When to check for nulls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When you know id is suppose to exist as in the example below, is it good practice to check for nulls?

```
var submission = _ctx.Submissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

submission.Done = true;
_ctx.Submissions.Attach(submission);
_ctx.Entry(submission).State = EntityState.Modified;
_ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Almost always when you use `FirstOrDefault()` you should check for null immediately.

Comment: Is there a reason *not* to check for null? If `submission` was null, could you still do something useful?

Comment: `Attach` and changing `State` are redundant, the object returned from `DbSet<T>` is tracked by change tracker

Comment: Any time you are dealing with a reference type and it's unacceptable to throw `NullReferenceException`, you should check for null.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - If system is in unexpected state it is perfectly fine to let any any type of exception to be thrown. As OP said - this particular code never expected to return `null` - so no need to check ok to let whole request to fail. (I don't think `FirstOeDefault` is a good choice of method as I put in my answer).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not suggesting it's never OK to throw a null reference exception, but that the purpose of explicit null checks is to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If id is supposed to exist you do not check for null. In fact in this case you should query like this

```
_ctx.Submissions.Single(p => p.Id == id);
```

The Single method will throw an exception if the item is not found. On the other hand if you are building a WebAPI or have a specific not found page as the id is sent by the client (i.e. can result by something outside your code) you may use SingleOrDefault, then check for null and return appropriate HTTP status code or redirect to the appropriate page. Basically if null results from not validated data you should check and respond accordingly. If the arguments that cause null values are generated by code you should NOT check for null and in fact query in a way that may not result in null because otherwise you are just covering an error in your code.

This is my opinion which is a result of my personal experience. Note that not everyone agrees as is obvious by the different answers of a question I posted on programmers.stackexchange.com some time ago - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147480/should-one-check-for-null-if-he-does-not-expect-null

Answer (score 3):

You check for `null` when you cannot say with complete certainty that the object will *never* not be null.

With that said, you are using `FirstOrDefault()`. If it didn't find anything in the criteria, it will return you `null`.

Comment: The only way the id will not exist will be because of someone has gone in the DB and physically removed it (orphan record so to speak). As a developer, do I need to cater for 'mistake-updates' in the database?

Comment: @DrZeuso You need to cater for stuff you know could happen and might cause the program to fail ungracefully. If you know `id` could be null, then you should handle it so. You don't want stuff to crash the program. This is falling slightly into "opinion based" territory as some will want to handle with custom exceptions in try/catch or check for null and add in additional business logic code.

Comment: How about in case of, data will be good in Production env, but because we have crap data currently in DEV (null fields that shouldn't be etc), it's making my code crash in DEV. Do I fix up the data in DEV so it's not null so my program runs correctly? or check for nulls in my program?

Comment: @DrZeuso I see no reason why one should not handle errors that they know about. If you're fine with a top level try/catch catching them then there's nothing to change as long as it handles the error the way you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that there should *always* be an object, and that there not being an object in question would mean that there is a bug in the program somewhere, then you should use `First` not `FirstOrDefault`.  Doing this means that if one of your assumptions for this code ends up being violated you will be informed quickly, loudly, and as close to the source of the problem as possible.

`FirstOrDefault` should be used if it's entirely sensible for the query in question to have no items, resulting in a `null` value being returned.  If you are in this position, the program should work correctly if the query does in fact return `null`, or whatever else you need to do for the program to function appropriately.

What you want to avoid is putting yourself in the position where a program (incorrectly) assumes a query always has at least one item, but where you use `FirstOrDeafult` anyway.  Here you end up with NullReferenceExceptions, which can take extra debugging work to figure out where the *actual* problem is (a query with no items that should have had items).

Answer (score 1):

For resilient code you should definitely check and handle to see if `submission` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You check for the null values, if there is an error to be occured by passing a null value. You can check them in any way, either by using try catch block or using a an if else block.

You can check it, this way you can prevent the errors that might occur by a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

`FirstOrDefault` documents your intention as "the result I'm *expecting* may not contain items". In such case you should check for `null` and perform some reasonable fallback. Throwing exception at that point would look strange.

It sounds like in your case you *don't expect* empty result, so use `First` and handle exception somewhere higher on call stack or even let default exception handling to happen.